# How to authenticate with Simple JWT using only password

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

After implementing [Simple JWT](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) I can login using username and password but User needs to authenticate only with password. I tried to override the `TokenObtainPairSerializer` like this

```
class CustomTokenPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField(required=False)

    def validate(self, data):
        try:
            user = User.objects.filter(password=data.get("password"))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("No such user exists")

        credentials = {
            "password": data.get("password")
        }

        if user:
            user = user.first()
            credentials["password"] = user.username

        return super().validate(credentials)
```

and this is the view.

```
class CutomObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenPairSerializer
```

but it still requires username. Can anyone help with this?

This is the User model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    password = models.CharField('password', max_length=4, validators=[MinLengthValidator(4)], unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    shift = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SHIFTS)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ROLES)
    work_start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    work_end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: What if multiple users have the *"exact same"* password?

Comment: doesn't adding 'unique=True' to password take care about that?